# Redirecting Response asynchronously in Custom HttpHandler ASP.Net MVC 5

Tags: c#, asynchronous, asp.net-mvc-5, async-await, mvcroutehandler

When response is redirected through Task aync and await.Redirection cannot not be seen on client side(Browser). Browser is waiting for response always. Basically I created a custom HttpHandler which is furthur returning MVCHandler thus it is invoking

```
IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
```

I overrided this method for redirection but redirection is going through another thread(or something).

```
protected override IAsyncResult BeginProcessRequest(HttpContext httpContext, AsyncCallback callback, object state)
    {
        if (_hasPermission)
        {
            return base.BeginProcessRequest(httpContext, callback, state);
        }
        else
        {
            return DisplayError(httpContext.Response);
        }
    }

 public async Task DisplayError(HttpResponse _response)
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            _response.RedirectToRoute("Unauthorized");
        }).RunSynchronously();
    }
```

I also tried to make it synchronous by writing above and another method. But still the same problem.***Is there any way to fix this
Or preventing MVCHandler to invoke `ProcessRequest` instead of `BeginProcessRequest` method?***

Comment: Why are you using `Task.Run`?

Comment: I checked without Run but no luck still my browser is still waiting for response and my next request is processing even very slow I cant see what is happening in debugger.May be that is waiting for request timeout. @mjwills

Answer (score 0):

The particular technology used to implement your HTTP server code (. NET/C#) in this case does not change the HTTP protocol.

You can change how you do stuff on the server (`async-await`), but you can't dasher the pipeline.

Comment: So what you are suggesting, means how should I implement this feature.